# Parameter can not be to a local variable

Tags: java, android, json

Есть метод, в него передаю 2 параметра:

```
public JSONObject convertToJSON(ArrayList<Map<String, String>> mapList, JSONObject jObj) {
    JsonFromObject jsonFromObject = new JsonFromObject();
    jObj = jsonFromObject.toJSON(id_num, hash, mapList);
    return jObj;
}
```

На второй параметр - `JSONObject jObj` ругается, что

> Parameter can not be to a local variable

Внутри метода объект в `json` преобразуется, но возвращает его пустым.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ну... А зачем вам передавать его в виде аргумента, если вы его сразу же переназначаете?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, идея была такая, что в этот объект запишется `json`, который формируется из другого метода.

Answer (score 1):

Указатель на объект (в данном случае `jObj`) передается по значению. Это значит, что в строке:

```
jObj = jsonFromObject.toJSON(id_num, hash, mapList);
```

указатель изменяется и теперь ссылается на другую область памяти (не затрагивая "внешний" объект, который был передан в качестве аргумента).

То есть:

```
JSONObject obj = null;
JSONObject res = convertToJSON(map, obj);
// Здесь и далее obj так и остался null.
// А вот res как раз хранит результат конвертации.
```

В данном случае достаточно просто удалить аргумент `jObj`, ибо он никак не используется внутри метода:

```
public JSONObject convertToJSON(List<Map<String, String>> mapList) {
    JsonFromObject jsonFromObject = new JsonFromObject();
    return jsonFromObject.toJSON(id_num, hash, mapList);
}
```

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы параметр использовался?

Comment: Если кратко, то никак (в том виде в каком хотите вы). Вы можете изменять внутреннее состояние объекта. Используйте возвращаемое значение. Либо необходимо тогда сделать обертку над `jObj`, но смысла я не вижу в этом.

Answer (score 1):

Вам не надо передавать в качестве аргумента ту переменную, кою вы хотите инициализировать с помощью метода. Сделайте как-то так:

```
void someMethod()
{
     ArrayList<Map<String, String>> mapList = ...;
     JSONObject jObj = convertToJSON(mapList);
}

public JSONObject convertToJSON(ArrayList<Map<String, String>> mapList) {
    return new JsonFromObject().toJSON(id_num, hash, mapList);;
}
```